# How to do I remove users from my list when someone leaves the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On my website, I have an active user tab but when you leave the page it doesn't remove you from the list. I have tried `window.onbeforeunload();` and `$(window).on('beforeunload', removeActiveUser());` to remove the client from the list. I tried making the code call an alert, and the alert showed up right after the page loaded, not when you were closing the page. Is there a way to do it without server side code? If I do need server side what would it be?

```
function removeActiveUser() {
    var i = 0;
    delay(1000);
    var keys = currentActiveUsers;
    var table = currentActiveUsers2;
    for (i; i < keys.length; i++) {
        var l = keys.length;
        var k = keys[i];
        console.log(k);
        var name = table[k].Name;
        var link = new Firebase("https://firebaseio.com/ActiveUsers/" + table[k]);
        //var link2 = new Firebase("https://firebaseio.com/error/);
        if (name == Name && table[k].Id == cId) {
            link.remove();
        }
    }
}
$(window).on('beforeunload', removeActiveUser());
```

Comment: So, how are you getting a list of users to begin with? Is Firebase your data store? What code do you use to add users? What are the listeners you have on your db?

Comment: yes, firebase is my data store, and here is the code https://pastebin.com/9KRJPDZg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your main problem is **triggering an action when the user leaves the page** (correct me if I misunderstood you there)

If that's the case then one of the solutions I'd use is to send out an http request every n seconds.

Since you're using firebase you can have your client JS update an entry against that user (let's call it alive_timestamp) and every n seconds update it, so your table would look like:

```
[ 
  {
    user: 'nick',
    alive: '1521677841583'
  }, 
  {
    user: 'alex',
    alive: '1521677621325'
  }
]
```

On your JS you'd have a function that reads this particular field and has a rule: `if Date.now() - user.alive < y then removeActiveUser(user)`

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with "Date" in js. Would you mind elaborating on the code to get the time?